# To restrict commit in SVN if message is not there

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I want to restrict user to commit a change if mandatory 20 chars commit message is not there.

From the SVN website, i am trying to add below pre-commit hook but it is not working for me.

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
check-logmessage "%1" -t "%2" ^
--min-size 20
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b 1
```

When i am trying to commit in tortoise git getting below error.

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: VisualSVNServerHooks: E720003: Can't open file 'E:\SVN\format': The system  
Error:  cannot find the path specified.  
Error: This error was generated by a custom hook script on the Subversion server.  
Error: Please contact your server administrator for help with resolving this issue.
```

Comment: The hook attached to your question works fine in my environment. If E:\SVN is a repository, then the file E:\SVN\format must be present. The SVN repository can be considered corrupt and is typically inaccessible by SVN clients when the format file is missing. So where are you’re repositories stored and is the file present or missing?

Comment: Thanks, Got the issue, there was a space in directory name "SVN MIGRATION" because of this it was failing.

Could you please let me know one more thing? I am using a community version of 4.0.0 . Number of users are 18 currently but the limit is 15. What will happen in this case? Is this applied for write users or for both? what operations are not available in case of limit breach?

Comment: See “What happens when the number of active users exceeds the license size?” at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00148/ And note that version 4.0 isn’t supported. You need to upgrade to the latest 5.3.